# Is there a way to set default settings for repositories in BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket

For all of my repositories I would like to have the issues service added, and I would like to have one of my friends as an admin to all of the repositories.

It is getting annoying having to set this up for every repository. Is there any way to set default settings for all repositories?

Answer (score 1):

**Adding your friend as an admin:**

You can [put him into a group](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Managing+Groups#ManagingGroups-Exampleofcreatingagroup) and add that group to your account with **admin** permissions.

See [Groups for Providing Access](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repository+privacy,+permissions,+and+more#Repositoryprivacy,permissions,andmore-GroupsforProvidingAccess).
Quote from the link:

> **Groups for Providing Access**
>
> When you create a repository, Bitbucket checks to see if the owner's
>   account has any groups with a default permissions (**read**, **write**, or
>   **admin**) assigned. If you do, it adds that group to the new repository
>   with the default permission.

---

**Adding the issues service:**

In the meantime they automated adding the issues service for new repositories. You still have to enable the issue tracker itself, though.

See [Enabling an Issue Tracker](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Enabling+an+Issue+Tracker) in the Bitbucket docs.
Quote from the link:

> **How the Issues service supports the issue tracker**
>
> If you enabled an issue tracker on your repository after August 2012,
>   Bitbucket adds the **Issues** service automatically for you when you
>   enable the Issue Tracker.  Older repositories with older issue
>   trackers may or may not have this service.